# columns are not coming in order like in xml to datagrid

Tags: xml, apache-flex, datagrid

My webapplication is giving XML in following format:

```
<Vendor name="Infosys Limited" adopTotal="120" totalstrength="775" FY10Q1="162" FY10Q2="132" FY10Q3="229" FY10Q4="254" FY11Q1="282" FY11Q2="243" FY11Q3="238" FY11Q4="233" FY12Q1="237" FY12Q2="136" FY12Q3="101" FY12Q4="120"/>
<Vendor name="Wipro" adopTotal="42" totalstrength="1181" FY10Q1="9" FY10Q2="12" FY10Q3="53" FY10Q4="67" FY11Q1="85" FY11Q2="76" FY11Q3="84" FY11Q4="82" FY12Q1="98" FY12Q2="51" FY12Q3="39" FY12Q4="42"/>
<Vendor name="Zensar Technologies Inc" adopTotal="187" totalstrength="1408" FY10Q1="207" FY10Q2="197" FY10Q3="428" FY10Q4="490" FY11Q1="511" FY11Q2="479" FY11Q3="471" FY11Q4="440" FY12Q1="440" FY12Q2="308" FY12Q3="137" FY12Q4="187"/>
<Vendor name="Hcl Technologies Limited" adopTotal="0" totalstrength="342" FY10Q1="0" FY10Q2="0" FY10Q3="0" FY10Q4="0" FY11Q1="3" FY11Q2="0" FY11Q3="9" FY11Q4="0" FY12Q1="0" FY12Q2="1" FY12Q3="1" FY12Q4="0"/>
<Vendor name="Mahindra Satyam" adopTotal="73" totalstrength="12" FY10Q1="106" FY10Q2="69" FY10Q3="50" FY10Q4="63" FY11Q1="117" FY11Q2="203" FY11Q3="192" FY11Q4="195" FY12Q1="208" FY12Q2="139" FY12Q3="53" FY12Q4="73"/>
<Vendor name="TCS" adopTotal="48" totalstrength="106" FY10Q1="54" FY10Q2="75" FY10Q3="140" FY10Q4="164" FY11Q1="164" FY11Q2="140" FY11Q3="147" FY11Q4="134" FY12Q1="124" FY12Q2="83" FY12Q3="49" FY12Q4="48"/>
```

But Datagrid is not following the format. Column should come according to xml variables. 
The order of the columns are not like xml.

I have simply added dataprovider to datagrid.
Please help.

Thanks 
Rimi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datagrid definition:

```
<s:DataGrid id="datagrid" dataProvider="{dp}"/>
```

When you receive data from backend, call the following function for each attribute in your xml:

```
private function addDataGridColumn(dataField:String):void
{
    var dgc:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn(dataField);
    var cols:Array = datagrid.columns;
    cols.push(dgc);
    datagrid.columns = cols;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to define your columns explicitly, like this:

```
<s:DataGrid dataProvider="{dp}">
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="@name" headerText="Name" />
            <s:GridColumn dataField="@adopTotal" headerText="Adop" />
            <s:GridColumn dataField="@totalstrength" headerText="Strength" />
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
</s:DataGrid>
```

And it's very similar with the old mx DataGrid:

```
<mx:DataGrid dataProvider="{dp}">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="..." headerText="..." />
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

The `dataField` property determines which property you want to display in that column.
The `headerText` property determines the label that will be displayed in the column header. 
The `@` sign refers to an XML attribute; you don't need it with regular collections.

Comment: Hi RIAstar,

Thanks for reply. But columns (xml attributes) are creating by webservice. It is dynamic.

Is it any other way to generate the columns? Please help.

Thanks

Comment: @mukherjeerimi As you can see, the 'columns' property is an Array in one case and and IList in the other. In both cases you can thus create the column classes dynamically. However, there is no order in XML attributes, so if you wish the columns to be defined on the server side, you'll have to send that information along.

Answer (score 0):

The way you declare the properties does not reflect the order of the properties are read internal. To ensure the right order of the columns manually create them in your datagrid.

For example

```
        <mx:DataGrid id="dg" width="100%" height="100%" rowCount="5" dataProvider="{employees}">
            <mx:columns>
                <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="@name" headerText="Name"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="@adopTotal" headerText="Total"/>
                 <....

            </mx:columns>
        </mx:DataGrid>
```