# To keep column order as dataprovider in flex datagrid

Tags: xml, apache-flex, datagrid

I am getting xml by webservice and want to display it to datagrid. But the columns are not coming in order to dataprovider. plese find xmldata below:

```
<Vendor name="Infosys Limited" adopTotal="120" totalstrength="775" FY10Q1="162" FY10Q2="132" FY10Q3="229" FY10Q4="254" FY11Q1="282" FY11Q2="243" FY11Q3="238" FY11Q4="233" FY12Q1="237" FY12Q2="136" FY12Q3="101" FY12Q4="120"/>
<Vendor name="Wipro" adopTotal="42" totalstrength="1181" FY10Q1="9" FY10Q2="12" FY10Q3="53" FY10Q4="67" FY11Q1="85" FY11Q2="76" FY11Q3="84" FY11Q4="82" FY12Q1="98" FY12Q2="51" FY12Q3="39" FY12Q4="42"/>
<Vendor name="Zensar Technologies Inc" adopTotal="187" totalstrength="1408" FY10Q1="207" FY10Q2="197" FY10Q3="428" FY10Q4="490" FY11Q1="511" FY11Q2="479" FY11Q3="471" FY11Q4="440" FY12Q1="440" FY12Q2="308" FY12Q3="137" FY12Q4="187"/>
<Vendor name="Hcl Technologies Limited" adopTotal="0" totalstrength="342" FY10Q1="0" FY10Q2="0" FY10Q3="0" FY10Q4="0" FY11Q1="3" FY11Q2="0" FY11Q3="9" FY11Q4="0" FY12Q1="0" FY12Q2="1" FY12Q3="1" FY12Q4="0"/>
<Vendor name="Mahindra Satyam" adopTotal="73" totalstrength="12" FY10Q1="106" FY10Q2="69" FY10Q3="50" FY10Q4="63" FY11Q1="117" FY11Q2="203" FY11Q3="192" FY11Q4="195" FY12Q1="208" FY12Q2="139" FY12Q3="53" FY12Q4="73"/>
<Vendor name="TCS" adopTotal="48" totalstrength="106" FY10Q1="54" FY10Q2="75" FY10Q3="140" FY10Q4="164" FY11Q1="164" FY11Q2="140" FY11Q3="147" FY11Q4="134" FY12Q1="124" FY12Q2="83" FY12Q3="49" FY12Q4="48"/>
```

In datagrid name attribute is coming at last. I can not keep in flex code because column count may increase.  Please help.

Thanks
Rimi

Comment: Please do not repost the same question twice (and read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)). This is an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11119962/columns-are-not-coming-in-order-like-in-xml-to-datagrid (for which you even already accepted an answer). This makes it harder for other users to find good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below code:- this may give you some idea: -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               >
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
        <fx:XML id="sampleXML" >
            <contacts>
                <Vendor name="Infosys Limited" adopTotal="120" totalstrength="775" FY10Q1="162" FY10Q2="132" FY10Q3="229" FY10Q4="254" FY11Q1="282" FY11Q2="243" FY11Q3="238" FY11Q4="233" FY12Q1="237" FY12Q2="136" FY12Q3="101" FY12Q4="120"/>
                <Vendor name="Wipro" adopTotal="42" totalstrength="1181" FY10Q1="9" FY10Q2="12" FY10Q3="53" FY10Q4="67" FY11Q1="85" FY11Q2="76" FY11Q3="84" FY11Q4="82" FY12Q1="98" FY12Q2="51" FY12Q3="39" FY12Q4="42"/>
                <Vendor name="Zensar Technologies Inc" adopTotal="187" totalstrength="1408" FY10Q1="207" FY10Q2="197" FY10Q3="428" FY10Q4="490" FY11Q1="511" FY11Q2="479" FY11Q3="471" FY11Q4="440" FY12Q1="440" FY12Q2="308" FY12Q3="137" FY12Q4="187"/>
                <Vendor name="Hcl Technologies Limited" adopTotal="0" totalstrength="342" FY10Q1="0" FY10Q2="0" FY10Q3="0" FY10Q4="0" FY11Q1="3" FY11Q2="0" FY11Q3="9" FY11Q4="0" FY12Q1="0" FY12Q2="1" FY12Q3="1" FY12Q4="0"/>
                <Vendor name="Mahindra Satyam" adopTotal="73" totalstrength="12" FY10Q1="106" FY10Q2="69" FY10Q3="50" FY10Q4="63" FY11Q1="117" FY11Q2="203" FY11Q3="192" FY11Q4="195" FY12Q1="208" FY12Q2="139" FY12Q3="53" FY12Q4="73"/>
                <Vendor name="TCS" adopTotal="48" totalstrength="106" FY10Q1="54" FY10Q2="75" FY10Q3="140" FY10Q4="164" FY11Q1="164" FY11Q2="140" FY11Q3="147" FY11Q4="134" FY12Q1="124" FY12Q2="83" FY12Q3="49" FY12Q4="48"/>
            </contacts>
        </fx:XML>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.controls.advancedDataGridClasses.AdvancedDataGridColumn;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            private function createADGColumn():void
            {
                var attributes:XMLList = sampleXML.Vendor[0].@*;
                var length:int = attributes.length();
                var columns:Array = myADG.columns;
                for(var i:Number=0; i<length; i++)
                {
                    var adgColumn:AdvancedDataGridColumn = new AdvancedDataGridColumn();
                    adgColumn.headerText = String(attributes[i].localName()).toLocaleUpperCase();
                    adgColumn.dataField = "@"+attributes[i].localName();
                    columns.push(adgColumn);
                    myADG.columns = columns;
                } 
                myADG.dataProvider = sampleXML.Vendor;
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="myADG" x="50" y="50"
                         width="900" height="400" creationComplete="createADGColumn()"
                         variableRowHeight="true" />
</s:Application>
```

Comment: Just as a question: is there a reason why using AdvancedDatagrid instead of DataGrid ?

Comment: NO there is no reason, as i like ADG for such samples. You can change AdvancedDatagrid to DataGrid to achieve the same.(Replace AdvancedDataGridColumn to DataGridColumn and remove variableRowHeight property).....

Comment: Thanks Mahesh. It helped me a lot.

Rimi

Comment: @MaheshP, while your example is very good I just want to point that the AdvancedDataGrid and the Datagrid are not the same thing. There are performance considerations between the 2 of them, and as longs as you do not have a hierarchical "tree-like" tructure that you may expand inside the advanceddatagrid then the usage of AdvancedDataGrid is not justified.